# Load the truck halfway

Tags: meaning

> When I arrived at the warehouse , they have already loaded **half of** truck.
>
> When I arrived at the warehouse , they have already loaded the truck **halfway**.
>
> When I arrived at the warehouse , they have already loaded the truck **half**.
>
> When I arrived at the warehouse , they have already loaded **half of** truck **in a half way**.
>
> When I arrived at the warehouse , they have already loaded the truck **up to the half of its capacity**.

Do all these sentences mean the same? Are all uses of “half” correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last is nearly grammatical (needs *had* rather than *had*, and delete *the* before *half*), but unlikely to be said except in a formal or official context.

The third ("halfway"), if similarly amended, sounds all right in context (but when I saw the title of the question I wondered what on earth it meant).

The way I would say it is

> When I arrived at the warehouse , they ha**d** already **half** loaded the truck.

Comment: Could you please clarify why you believe the last sentence is grammatical? **Present Perfect** is used to describe an event that completed before the arrival. But that contradicts the sequence of tenses because for such case **Past Perfect** should be used (or **Past Simple**). You actually suggest using it at the end of your  post.

Comment: @Anatolii: you're right: I didn't read it carefully. It's grammatical with some corrections. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I still believe in neither of the sentences using **Present Perfect** is correct because, as mentioned before, it contradicts the sequence of tenses  So, I disagree with your statement `The third ("halfway") sounds all right in context` but I'm not a native English speaker as you're so I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: No, you're right again, @Anatolii: I simply wasn't looking at the verb forms, because I was focussing on the _half_ that the OP asked about. I've edited my answer again.

Comment: Now I agree with your answer :) Thanks!